# How to fix "Cannot connect to server" error when trying to open FQDN from Azure Container Instances?

Tags: azure, connection, fqdn, azure-container-instances

I'm currently trying to deploy my first container with the Azure Container Instance. Everything worked fine so far, but when I use az container show and browse the FQDN I get an error message:

> Cannot connect to server

The page cannot be displayed. The page you are looking for is currently unavailable.

The internet connection is up and I can connect to everything else.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the ACI, there are some things you should pay attention to:

1. Make sure the docker image can work fine locally
2. The port you expose is right, both in the docker image and create ACI
3. The ACI is in the running state

Check above and when you browse the FQDN you can add the port at the end just like: `FQDN:port`.

Any more question please give me the message.

Comment: Hi, my image runs locally. Also I have the right port und my ACI is in running state :) it still doesn't work. Maybe another idea?

Comment: When you create the ACI, the port is also right? Which port do you expose?

Comment: So you browse the FQDN with the port?

Comment: Yes I do. Fqdn:8080

Comment: You can provide the image if you do not mind, then I will test for you.

Comment: By the way, do you use the public IP?

Comment: @nataliefoerster What is the exact issue?